# AddCampaigns.php example for AdWords API returns internal_failure error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I've been trying to use the AdWords API.
I followed all the steps from 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start?hl=es

I also used this as a reference:

http://www.sagerock.com/blog/setting-google-adwords-api-access-first-time/

I thought I had all properly setted but when I run the AddCampaigns.php from the examples folder it returns:
*An error has occurred: { "error" : "internal_failure" }*
which comes from:

```
try {
    // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
    // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
    $user = new AdWordsUser();
    $user->SetClientCustomerId("123-456-7891"); // Here I add the client test account ID
    // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
    $user->LogAll();

    // Run the example.
    AddCampaignsExample($user);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
}
```

My auth.ini file looks like:

```
developerToken = "my not yet aproved developer token"
userAgent = "my company name"  

clientCustomerId = "123-456-7892" // Here I have the Manager test account ID

[OAUTH2] 

client_id = "123123123123-asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret = "My_client_secret"        
refresh_token = "the refresh token i got from getrefreshtoken.php"
```

I don't know where the problem comes from. The examples are suposed to work only via command line but I commented this code:

```
//if (__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
//    return;
//}
```

so I can run it from on the server with my browser. I don't know if that's the cause of the error that I get. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It finally worked without changing absolutely anything so This settings seem to be fine. In fact, when I launched the AddCampaigns.php again It returned an invalid_grant error instead so I generated a new refresh token and it worked at the next try.